# Yank file name / path of current buffer in Vim

Tags: vim, clipboard, yank

Assuming the current buffer is a file open for edit, so `:e` does not display `E32: No file name`.

I would like to yank one or all of:

- The file name exactly as show on the status line, e.g. `~\myfile.txt`
- A full path to the file, e.g. `c:\foo\bar\myfile.txt`
- Just the file name, e.g. `myfile.txt`

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/741024/80161 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/2233905/80161

Comment: To clipboard: http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3686/copy-the-full-path-of-current-buffer-to-clipboard

Answer (score 292, accepted):

**TL;DR**

`:let @" = expand("%")`

this will copy the file name to the *unamed register*, then you can use good old `p` to paste it. and of course you can map this to a key for quicker use.

`:nmap cp :let @" = expand("%")<cr>`

you can also use this for full path

`:let @" = expand("%:p")`

**Explanation**

Vim uses the *unnamed register* to store text that has been deleted or copied (yanked), likewise when you paste it reads the text from this register.

Using `let` we can manually store text in the register using `:let @" = "text"` but we can also store the result of an expression.

In the above example we use the function `expand` which expands wildcards and keywords. in our example we use `expand('%')` to expand the current file name. We can modify it as `expand('%:p')` for the full file name.

See `:help let` `:help expand` `:help registers` for details

Comment: Cool just added this to my vimrc:


noremap <silent> <F4> :let @+=expand("%:p")<CR>

Comment: On Windows, you should instead use :let @* = expand("%"), if you want it to be in the _Windows_ clipboard.

Comment: If you are using `unnamedplus` as your clipboard use `let @+ = expand("%")`

Comment: Use `"%:h"` to get the full path without the filename.

Comment: Related, in particular if you need the directory without filename - https://stackoverflow.com/a/2233924/1882064

Comment: Is there any reason why one wouldn't just use the `%` register?  ie `"%p` ?

Answer (score 134):

Almost what you're asking for, and it might do: in `INSERT` mode, `Ctrl+R %` pulls the current filename into where you are (command prompt, edit buffer, ...). See [this Vim Tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Insert_current_filename) for more.

Comment: when you exit edit mode you can add the file name: ctrl-" ctrl-% p

Comment: `Ctrl+R %` works while in `insert` mode -- but in `edit` mode, `Ctrl+R` means redo.

Comment: What stefanB meant was "%p for normal/command mode.  That's the same as <C-r>% in insert/cmdline-mode.

Comment: Just to resummarize or state differently: the answers for both graywh and dwc are "paste from register %".  One does this for insert mode, the other for normal mode.  In macvim, it appears the % register can't be overwritten.

Comment: is there the same simple command to get linenumber ? ) thx for solution

Comment: This only gets filename not complete path.

Answer (score 124):

If you want to put the current buffer filename in your system-level clipboard, try changing the register to @+:

```
" relative path
:let @+ = expand("%")

" full path
:let @+ = expand("%:p")

" just filename
:let @+ = expand("%:t")
```

---

Edit 20140421:
I commonly use these, so I created some shortcuts. [Linux Vims apparently operate slightly differently than Mac Vims](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489428/how-to-make-vim-paste-from-and-copy-to-systems-clipboard), so there is a special case for that as well. If you put the following in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
" copy current file name (relative/absolute) to system clipboard
if has("mac") || has("gui_macvim") || has("gui_mac")
  " relative path  (src/foo.txt)
  nnoremap <leader>cf :let @*=expand("%")<CR>

  " absolute path  (/something/src/foo.txt)
  nnoremap <leader>cF :let @*=expand("%:p")<CR>

  " filename       (foo.txt)
  nnoremap <leader>ct :let @*=expand("%:t")<CR>

  " directory name (/something/src)
  nnoremap <leader>ch :let @*=expand("%:p:h")<CR>
endif

" copy current file name (relative/absolute) to system clipboard (Linux version)
if has("gui_gtk") || has("gui_gtk2") || has("gui_gnome") || has("unix")
  " relative path (src/foo.txt)
  nnoremap <leader>cf :let @+=expand("%")<CR>

  " absolute path (/something/src/foo.txt)
  nnoremap <leader>cF :let @+=expand("%:p")<CR>

  " filename (foo.txt)
  nnoremap <leader>ct :let @+=expand("%:t")<CR>

  " directory name (/something/src)
  nnoremap <leader>ch :let @+=expand("%:p:h")<CR>
endif
```

Then for example `<leader>cf` will copy the relative path of the current buffer (the default leader is backslash (`\`)). I often use these for running commands on a file or doing other things on the command line. I don't really use the last filename / directory name often.

You might consider more intuitive mappings like `<leader>cfr` for relative, `<leader>cfa` for absolute, `<leader>cff` for just filename, `<leader>cfd` for directory.

Comment: On windows and mac `"*` and `"+` are equivalent, so you can dispense with the platform checks and just use `@+`

Comment: Oddly enough this doesn't seem to work in a vimscript function:  "echo bufname('%:p')" is blank, but you can fix this with the longer "fnamemodify(bufname('%'),':p')"

Comment: Perfect. The key maps are logical. It's portable. Grabs anything out of the path you should want

Answer (score 21):

Answer tested on Neovim/Ubunutu.

```
:let @+=@%
```

From what I can tell, the `%` register already contains the relative filepath, so it's as simple as moving the contents of the `%` register to whatever register represents your favourite clipboard.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1502258/2071807) deals with copying from one register to another

Seems pretty straightforward to me. No need for any hard-to-remember `expand()` stuff.

Answer (score 12):

If you do `:reg` you will see the name of the current file in the `%` register. You can paste it with `"%p`, for example.

If, like me, you often switch to the 'alternate' buffer, it is very handy that its full path-and-file-name are put in the `#` register. You can paste it with `"#p`, for example.

Note (just in case this is behaviour specific to my setup): I am using VIM 7.4.52 on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS.

Answer (score 4):

Combining information from a couple of other answers: If you want to yank the current full path to a file and put it into the command buffer in another window, first do `:let @" = expand("%:p")`, then move to another window and type `Ctrl+R "`.

Useful for copying a file while staying in the same directory and keeping the old one open. For example:

> **Start**: Editing *src/com/benatkin/paint/shapes/Circle.java*
>
> 1. Type `:let @" = expand("%:p")` *(The path gets yanked to the main clipboard buffer.)*
> 2. Open a new window with `:sp`
> 3. Type `:e Ctrl+R"`
> 4. Use the arrow keys to go back to Circle and change it to Square, and press <CR>
>
> **End**: Editing *src/com/benatkin/paint/shapes/Square.java*

Answer (score 3):

If you're on terminal vim, and want to copy to **system** clipboard: For something easy to remember, that doesn't  requiring predefined mappings/functions:

```
:!echo %
```

prints the current buffer's relative path to terminal, where you can copy it and then ENTER back to vim. (as already mentioned, you can postfix the command with `:p` or `:t` to get absolute or basename,  if you can remember that....)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution:

```
" filename / dirname of the current file {{{
    " copy result to the system clipboard and echo the result
    " the cb> prompt means the clipboard
    " *f*ile *n*ame, ex. init.vim
    map <Leader>fn :let @+ = expand("%:t") \| echo 'cb> ' . @+<CR>
    " *f*ile *p*ath, ex. /home/user/nvim/init.vim
    map <Leader>fp :let @+ = expand("%:p") \| echo 'cb> ' . @+<CR>
    " *d*irectory *p*ath, ex. /home/user/nvim
    map <Leader>dp :let @+ = expand("%:p:h") \| echo 'cb> ' . @+<CR>
    " *d*irectory *n*ame, ex. nvim
    map <Leader>dn :let @+ = expand("%:p:h:t") \| echo 'cb> ' . @+<CR>
" }}}
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to other answers, if you happen to have [vim-fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) installed, you can use default `y<C-G>` (that's `y` followed by `Ctrl`+`g`) mapping.

From `:help vim-fugitive`:

```
                                                *fugitive_y_CTRL-G*
["x]y<C-G>              Yank the path to the current |fugitive-object|.
```

Even though it specifies `fugitive-object` it actually works on usual files too, yanking file path.

For me it's even simpler to remember than having to remember how to use `expand`. And there's no need to create extra mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I put it in my vimc:

```
nnoremap yl :let @" = expand("%:p")<cr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using map commands (`:h map-commands`), this might be an ideal application for using abbreviations (`:h abbreviations`). They behave like TextExpander, but are native to Vim.

Start by adding the following lines to `$MYVIMRC`. Change the trigger (the `<y..>` to suit your preferences.

```
cabbrev yfn   :let @+ = expand("%:t")
cabbrev yfp   :let @+ = expand("%:p")
cabbrev yrp   :let @+ = expand("%")
```

Using `$MYVIMRC` as an example:

- `yfn` — `%:t` tail (filename, last path component only); e.g. cwd: `~/<any/dir>/`, result: `.vimrc`
- `yfp` — `%:p` expand to full path; e.g. cwd: `~/any/dir/`, result:  `/Users/<home_dir>/.vimrc`
- `yrp` —  `%` current file name (relative path); e.g. cwd: `~/`, result:   `.vimrc`

So, in command-line mode, `<:cabbrev> + <CR>` executes the command immediately, or you can start editing it right away.

Answer (score 0):

If you run vim from the terminal, you can use this:

```
!echo % | xclip -sel clip
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this to my vimrc:

```
function! GetLocation()
echo expand("%:p")
endfunction

command! GetLocation call GetLocation()
```

Source your vimrc then use :GetLocation
to get the path of the file in the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have nvim-tree (comes in NvChad), you can yank the path by simply using `Y` ([docs link](https://github.com/nvim-tree/nvim-tree.lua/blob/8cbb1db8e90b62fc56f379992e622e9f919792ce/doc/nvim-tree-lua.txt#L201)). The only catch is that **you have to be in the file tree**, not the code file buffer.

I know this isn't exactly what you asked for, but it's much simpler than the other suggestions and doesn't require customizations. I speak for a lot of reluctant NeoVim users in that I avoid customizations like the plague.

Answer (score -1):

I use xclip to access X's clipboard, so I use:

```
nmap <localleader>d :call system("xclip -i -selection clipboard", expand("%:p"))<CR>
```

Comment: "+ or "* do the same thing natively in vim without having to use an external command.

Answer (score -1):

If you wish to simply yank the path of the currently open file name then simply press:

1. step1: ctrl + g [You will see the entire root path at the bottom of window]
2. step2: select the path with the mouse
3. step3: Paste with the middle mouse wheel