# Copy from one register to another

Tags: vim, vim-registers

How to copy the contents of one register to another without pasting on clipboard? I'd yanked one text and it got yanked in the default `"` register. Now I want to copy another text without deleting/overwriting `"` register. So I want to move the contents of `"` register to say some `a` or `b` register so that I can copy the new text inside `"`. How to do this?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

To copy or swap values between registers you can use the [:let](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#:let) command, for example to copy the contents of the `b` register to `a`:

```
:let @a=@b
```

Or copy the contents of the `"` register to `a`:

```
:let @a=@"
```

Check this Vim Tip for some good key mapping suggestions:

- [Comfortable handling of registers](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Comfortable_handling_of_registers)

Comment: Somehow I cannot get this to work.  I have a pretty minimal vim on this mcahine. Here are some of my settings.  VIM - Vi IMproved 7.0 (2006 May 7, compiled Mar  5 2011 21:36:07) Included patches: 1, 3-4, 7-9, 11, 13-17, 19-26, 29-31, 34-44, 47, 50-56, 58-64,  66-73, 75, 77-92, 94-107, 109, 202, 34-237
Compiled by <bugzilla@redhat.com> 
Tiny version without GUI.

Comment: @Paul, as far I remember the *small* and *tiny* feature sets of Vim do not support the `:let` command.

Comment: Can you explain what `@` does?

Comment: `@` is the way of working with registers as variables. See `:help let-register` for details. You can basically just think of it as `@a` being the variable where register `a` is stored.

Answer (score 10):

You can do something like this:

```
let @a = getreg('"')
```

That'll copy the `"` register to the `a` register.