# Notepad++: how to get filename / path of current file and put it into the clipboard in notepad plus plus

Tags: notepad++, clipboard

Editing files with VIM I can easily copy & paste the name ( or the full path ) of the file 
I'm working on ( to understand what I mean about VIM you can see: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916875/yank-file-name-path-of-current-buffer-in-vim) or [wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Get_the_name_of_the_current_file) );

Is there an  equivalent solution by using [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) ?, how can I do?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Notepad++ has no *default shortcut* to do that, but:

open menu: "Edit" (Alt-E) then select: "Copy to clipboard" and you have different options to 
copy the fully qualified file name for current document or parts of it.

See [this wiki](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php?title=Clipboard_Uses) for exhaustive reference.

Answer (score 19):

Another solution is to right-click on the tab, which will let you get the file name/path from there. However, I have tabs disabled, so I have to go with Franco's solution.

Answer (score 3):

There is no default shortcut key to copy file name or path but you can create one.

Go to Settings->Shortcut mapper
scroll down and look for "Current File path to Clipboard"
click on the empty cell next to it and provide the shortcut of your choice.