# How can I expand the full path of the current file to pass to a command in Vim?

Tags: vim

When I go to command mode and type

```
:!mycommand %
```

I get my command executed on the current file (`%` is expanded to the current file name).
Is there a similar construct that expands the full file name (with the full path)?

I am using Windows.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/741024/80161 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/916875/80161

Comment: :!mycommand "%"

Answer (score 174, accepted):

`:!mycommand %:p`

Related:

`:!cd %:p:h`

Comment: How do you find these in VIM help?

Comment: @keflavich `:help filename-modifiers`

Comment: to get directory which contains current file, I think that %:h is enough. Why need %:p:h here?

Comment: @HVNSweeting `:%p` is the absolute path to the file, rather than the relative path. `:%p%h` is the absolute path to the file's parent directory. Using just `%:h` can result in a relative path.

Comment: @AdamBackstrom can you give an example? I always got absolute path with %:h

Comment: @HVNSweeting Shell: `cd ~ ; vim .vimrc`, Vim: `:!echo %:h`, should display '.' for the relative path.

Comment: thanks, that's right, I always use cd %:h to cd to current file's dir, so it's always show fullpath.

Comment: there is also `%:.`, that return the file path relative to the current directory - often more convenient that the absolute path

Answer (score 66):

The other two answers didn’t work for me (for some reason). However, I found that this combo displays the full path when typed in Normal mode:

Press <kbd>1</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>

Source: “[Get the name of the current file](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Get_the_name_of_the_current_file)” on the Vim Tips Wiki. See also the `{count}CTRL-G` section of [`:help CTRL-G`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#CTRL-G).

Comment: That's a different topic. The question is about including the buffer path in a command string (thus the leading `:!`). Your `{count}CTRL-G` sequence is for displaying the full path in the UI.

Comment: @StefanMajewsky regarding the question title which in fact brought me here, this should be the chosen answer.

Answer (score 29):

Append `:p`, e.g.

```
:!mycommand %:p
```

And `%:p:h` will give you the path of the directory that the file resides in.

Answer (score 21):

To print out the current vim filename:

```
:help expand
:echo expand("%:p")    " absolute path
:echo expand("%:p:h")  " absolute path dirname
:echo expand("%:p:h:h")" absolute path dirname dirname
:echo expand("%:.")    " relative path
:echo expand("%:.:h")  " relative path dirname
:echo expand("%:.:h:h")" relative path dirname dirname

:echo expand("<sfile>:p")  " absolute path to [this] vimscript

:help filename-modifiers
```

For example (with a vim function), to `resolve()` and `expand()` any symlinks to the absolute path to the current script `<sfile>:p` (instead of `%:p`), and then `exec` to `source` the `fnameescape`-ed filename contained in a function-local vim variable `l:vimrcfilename`:

```
 "  g:__sfile__dirname     -- directory containing this vimrc script
 "                            after symlinks
 "                            ~dirname(abspath(realpath(__file__)))
 let g:__sfile__dirname=fnamemodify(resolve(expand("<sfile>:p")), ":h")

 "  Source_dotvim(filename)  -- source dirname(this_vimrc)/filename
 function Source_dotvim(filename)
     let l:vimrcfilename=g:__sfile__dirname . "/" . a:filename
     if filereadable(l:vimrcfilename) && !empty(l:vimrcfilename)
         "source s:vimrcfilename "this doesn't work, so exec:
         exec "source " . fnameescape(l:vimrcfilename)
     else
         echo l:vimrcfilename . " empty or not found."
     endif
 endfunction 

 call Source_dotvim("vimrc.local.01-env.vimrc")
```

Notes:

- `:help fnamemodify`
- "current file": `%:p` (buffer file) / `<sfile>:p` (script file)
- [`expand('<sfile>')` does not work from within a function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21338022/188833)
- [source `l:varname` does not work; so, `exec` - string concatenation - and `fnameescape`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14508800/188833)
- `:messages` prints the most-recent 200 vim [error,] messages

References

- [annika-backstrom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2233924/188833)
- [umber-ferrule's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11222188/188833)
- [tito-11's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24886244/188833)

Answer (score 2):

Get the name of the current file
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Get_the_name_of_the_current_file

Set_working_directory_to_the_current_file
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Set_working_directory_to_the_current_file

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the full path in your `vimrc`, you can use something like this:

```
let vimFiles = '$HOME/.vim'
let absPath  = expand(vimFiles . '/subDir')
```

This will give you a path with backslashes on Windows.