# Save file with new filename: append to existing filename

Tags: vim

Is there a simple way to (in VIM) do save the currently open file with it's current name plus an appended phrase?

IE, from `/home/affert/` type `vim /data/folder/file1.txt`

then save the file as `/data/folder/file1.txt_BACKUP` without needing to copy and paste the filename?

Context: I have a file that has full paths in it to other files in other folders.  I use `ctrl+W, ctrl+F` to open the file in a new window.  That's why I don't want to copy and paste.  BTW, the folder and file names are a lot longer, so typing them myself is not a useful option.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
:w %:p_BACKUP
```

For explanation see [How can I expand the full path of the current file to pass to a command in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233905/howto-get-full-path-of-current-file-in-vim).

Answer (score 15):

Easy:

```
 :w %_BACKUP
```

If you need override:

```
 :w %_BACKUP!
```

The it gonna answer:

```
"filename_BACKUP!" [New] XL, XC written
```