# How to save and overwrite in Vim when hitting E13?

Tags: vim

In my Vim editor I want to overwrite a file, so I type colon and start typing:

```
:saveas app/assets/javascripts/some.js
```

I get

```
E13: File exists (add ! to override)
```

How do I overwrite this file using *saveas* from Vim?

Comment: If says so in the message: `add ! to override`. So use `:saveas!`... Also be aware you can use `:help E13` to get more information (works with most error numbers).

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea where to put the exclamation point....and I didn't realize you could do help E13.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> :saveas! filename

Take a look at this answer as well, it explains how to use the existing name, if you wanted to create a ".backup" [Save file with new filename: append to existing filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953016/vim-save-file-with-new-filename-append-to-existing-filename)