# Get path of current file being sourced

Tags: vim

I am sourcing a local vimrc using the plugin from the first response here: [Vim: apply settings on files in directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456792/vim-apply-settings-on-files-in-directory)

Now what i'd like to do is to add the curren path of this local vimrc file to vims path.

I do know that `%:p:h` gives me the path of the current file. But it is of the file being opened not of the config file being soucred.

```
let s:local_path = expand('%:p:h')
exec "set path+=".s:local_path
```

Does anyone know how to get the path of the file being sourced?

Comment: Please explain your goal a bit more precisely.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get path to the current vimscript being executed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976776/how-to-get-path-to-the-current-vimscript-being-executed)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of `%`, just use the special `<sfile>`; in a script (but not inside a function within a script!), it is expanded to the file name of the sourced script:

```
:let s:local_path = expand('<sfile>:p:h')
```