# How to get path to the vim being executed in vimscript

Tags: filepath, vim

For example, in directory /abc the command vim def/my.txt would edit file /abc/def/my.txt. 
I want to get the path /abc in my vim plugin script, but I don't know which function can do it.

I have read related articles, like 
(Please add http:// to following items if you want to access, I don't have enough reputation to post more than 2 links o(╯□╰)o ):

- learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/40.html
- vim.wikia.com/wiki/Get_the_name_of_the_current_file
- [How to get path to the current vimscript being executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976776/how-to-get-path-to-the-current-vimscript-being-executed)

But useless.

Thanks.

==============================
I noticed at http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Get_the_name_of_the_current_file, it said:
:echo @%    def/my.txt  
I thought I found the hope. 
Because I can get /abc by minus def/my.txt from full path.
But I tested above command in my vim environment, it didn't work. It just print my.txt.

Comment: I am not sure which path do you want to get. you want to get usr's current dir? (under which dir the user has started vim?) vim's `:pwd and getcwd()` will give you that, as Ingo answered. However, user can in vim execute commands, which leading to the dir gets changed, like `:cd ..` or with `autochdir option`. in this case, you won't get that dir any more.  When your plugin function will be triggered?

Comment: I made commands in my vim plugin to call the path function, the design is that user need execute the commands once they launch "vim" or "vim some_path_to_file". So :cd .. will not have chance to impact it but autochdir maybe. But anyway, it doesn't matter to my logic, I just want to get the current dir where user execute "vim" with or without file name arguments. For more details, I explained why I found pwd and getcwd() not work in my cases. Thanks for your asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `:pwd` command / `getcwd()` function.

When you edit `def/my.txt` from `/abc`, the latter is your current directory, and all files are addressed relative to it. (Unless you have something like `:set autochdir`.)

For dealing with file paths, the `fnamemodify()` function is also very helpful; e.g. to turn filespecs into absolute ones (`:p` argument), or to cut off head, tail, or file extension.

Comment: Thanks. But I've found :pwd and getcwd() not work in my case. If I am at /abc/, then run "vim def/my.txt", then :pwd and getcwd() all return /abc/dev/, that's not my expectation. But if I just run "vim" at /abc/, then it will return /abc. Generally speaking, I want to get the dir where user run "vim" or "vim the_path_to_file".

Comment: Do you have the mentioned `'autochdir'`, or an equivalent `:autocmd`?! Because Vim doesn't normally behave that way. In any way, you could store Vim's CWD during startup by putting this into your `~/.vimrc`: `let g:cwd = getcwd()`.

Comment: And I've tried a few options with fnamemodify(), found nothing useful:( Yes! Good point @Ingo Karkat! I will examine my ~/.vimrc. I almost there :) Thanks a lot:)

Comment: Oh my god~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~You're right ::>_<::  There is "set autochdir" in it (●-●) Thanks a lot Ingo!

Comment: `:pwd` does not work for me but `:!pwd` does. However, I don't know how to execute the `getcwd()` function.