# Call luafile with a variable

Tags: vim

This seems like a trivial thing to accomplish, but I'd like to run a lua script alongside a vimscript (in the same directory).

First I tried

```
luafile ./somefile.lua
```

which doesn't work. I looked up how to [get the current vimscript's directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976776/how-to-get-path-to-the-current-vimscript-being-executed) and tried

```
let s:path = fnamemodify(resolve(expand('<sfile>:p')), ':h')
let s:vglua = s:path . "/somefile.lua"
luafile s:vglua
```

which, unsurprisingly, results in

> cannot open s:vglua: No such file or directory

I know I'm doing something stupid, but Vim's helpfiles are huge and I'm not seeing anything really helpful from my initial search queries.

How would I go about running a Lua script that's in the same directory as my vimscript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing `s:vglua` is correctly defined, you must:

```
execute "luafile " . s:vglua
```