# How to dynamically source a script?

Tags: vim

How can I source a vim script whose filename is contained in a variable?

Just like `:source`, except that the parameter isn't a string literal, but a variable name.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can always use `:execute` to build a command dynamically:

```
:execute 'source '.fnameescape(myvar)
```

Comment: Ahem, `escape()` takes an additional argument and is the wrong one; you probably meant `fnameescape()`.