# Why does vim "cancel out" the last two characters when running `%:8` in an external command?

Tags: vim, rspec

A simple work flow I often use when running an `rspec` test I have just been working on, in `vim`, is as follows:

```
15:   it "my example test" do
16:     expect(1 == 1).to be true
17:   end
```

And to run this test, you can do:

```
!rspec %:15
```

This runs `rspec` as an [external command](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/52.html). `%` expands to the current filename, and `:15` tells `rspec` to only run the test line `15`, rather than all tests in the file.

This technique works fine under normal circumstances. However, if you try to run a test on lines `80-89` then something strange happens:

```
84:   it "my other test" do
85:     expect(4 > 3).to be false
86:   end

!rspec %:84
```

This runs the command `rspec [filename]4` - i.e. the `:8` characters disappear! (And you get a "file not found" error.)

**A workaround to avoid this problem** is to press `TAB` after entering `%`, which immediately expands `%` to the full path name.

However, what's the reason behind this strange `vim` behaviour? Is it a bug, or a feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A different, [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233905/how-can-i-expand-the-full-path-of-the-current-file-to-pass-to-a-command-in-vim) led me to finding the answer to this.

You can find the answer, along with more detail, by running `:help filename-modifiers` in `vim`. Here is a summary of the key point:

> The file name modifiers can be used after `"%"`, `"#"`, `"#n"`, `"<cfile>"`, `"<sfile>"`, `"<afile>"` or `"<abuf>"`.
>
> `:8` Converts the path to 8.3 short format (currently only on MS-Windows).  Will act on as much of a path that is an existing path.

`8` is the only numerical filename-modifier. If you wish to disable this feature entirely, you can compile `vim` without the `+modify_fname` feature.