# Evaluating Current File for Ctags

Tags: vim, ctags

I'm trying to use `%<.cpp` to switch from my header to the associated cpp file.  I know there are plugins for this but I'd rather just use ctags straight.  I can open the header:

```
vsp | tag myfile.h
```

and my ctags recognizes that a file myfile.cpp exists. (vsp | tag myfile.cpp works as well).  It will not however recognize when I do the following from my header file:

```
vsp | tags %<.cpp
```

as it literaly interprets me as looking for the tag `%<.cpp`  any ideas?

Comment: What exactly does `vsp | tag myfile.h` do? When I try to run this it just splits window.

Comment: Have you tried using expand()? [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36501915/7560154)