# Get the file name without file extension in a Vim function

Tags: vim

I want to get the file name without the file extension in Vim.

I wrote the following function in my `.vimrc` file to compile and run the Java program:

```
:function! JAVA_RUN()
:!javac %^M
:endfunction

map <F3> :execute JAVA_RUN()<CR> :source $HOME/.vimrc<CR>
```

How can I get the file name without the extension inside the function?

Comment: You don't have to make a function to do that just `(map <F#> :!java %:r <Enter>)`

Answer (score 107, accepted):

`:help expand()` should give you the answer, see [expand()](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#expand()).

You should use the `r` modifier for %, with `%:r` instead of `%` to get the file name without extension.

If you want to write functions to build and execute files, you should also have a look at the documentation for [`shellescape`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#shellescape()), in order to prevent problems with spaces in file name or path.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! Used it as an easy way to convert current file formats without jumping out of vim.

Comment: Is there a difference between `%:r` and `%<`?

Comment: Yes there is, but it is subtle. `%<` is still supported for backward compatibility with 3.0, and is equivalent with `%:r`. The `:r` form is preferred. It can be combined with the other modifiers, and also can be used multiple times, for instance if you have multiple extensions, such as `.tar.gz`.

Comment: Generally speaking `%:r` will give the *root* (*:r*) of the path, not the file name without extension. See this: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Get_the_name_of_the_current_file

Answer (score 11):

If you want to expand a filename (other than `%` etc) take a look at `fnamemodify()`

```
fnamemodify({fname}, {mods})                *fnamemodify()*
        Modify file name {fname} according to {mods}.  {mods} is a
        string of characters like it is used for file names on the
        command line.  See |filename-modifiers|.
```

`fnamemodify("main.java", ":r")` returns `main`.

Answer (score 4):

I literally just read a similar question to this (in that someone else seemed to be trying to configure vim to build automagically for them with the F-key), and wrote [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17897346/2567285) about how you can leverage the power of vim's `:make` command without even needing to write a Makefile. In your case, it's less directly related to the question, but I thought I'd mention it in case you were interested.

Furthermore, someone seems to have written something on [Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Errorformat_for_java/ant/junit/cygwin/bash) about how to set up vim's `:make` command to specifically work with Java projects built with ant. I haven't worked with Java in a while myself, but in your case specifically it might be a good place to get started.

Answer (score 3):

I came here looking for an answer for a similar question. I wanted to be able to extract the current class name from the java file being edited. I found a very neat way to do this in vim with an abbreviation:

```
ab xclass <C-R>=expand('%:t:r')<CR>
```

Place this line in your .vimrc (or similar) for this to work. An abbreviation will auto-trigger as soon as you press space, and so I usually prefix them with 'x' to avoid their accidental expansion.

The trick here is the combination of `:t` and `:r` in the argument to `expand()`. `%` is the "current file name", `:t` selects just the **t**ail of the path ("last path component only") and `:r` selects just the **r**oot ("one extension removed"). (quoted parts are from the official *expand()* documentation.)

So when you are creating a new class in file `/a/b/ClassIAmAboutToCreate.java` you would type:

```
public class xclass {
```

the moment you press space after "xclass", the abbreviation will be expanded to `public class ClassIAmAboutToCreate`, which is exactly what you need.

Also, note that an abbreviation can be triggered by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> which avoids inserting a space after the class name.