# Define vim command to open current filename with another extension

Tags: vim, latex

I'm trying a simple way to compile pdfs in LaTeX and open them with zathura from a single autocmd inside vim, so far I tried:

```
command Latex !pdflatex %:t
command Za !zathura @%.pdf
autocmd FileType tex map <leader>pdf :w<CR>:Latex<CR>:Za <CR>
```

Obviously, `@%.pdf` is wrong, but I've had no luck in finding how to append an extension to the file name. I'm newbie in vim scripting so please point out any other errors.

Comment: The answer is at the same place you found `:t`.

Comment: that didn't help much...

Answer (score 0):

Since no one bother to answer, I came up with a shell solution for it, a script called *zatex*:

```sh
tex=".tex"
pdf=".pdf"
cd $1; 
texfile="$2$tex";
pdflatex $texfile;
pdffile="$2$pdf";
setsid zathura $pdffile;
```

And inside my .vimrc:

```
command Zatex !zatex %:p:h %:p:h:t
autocmd FileType tex map <leader>pdf :w<CR>:Zatex<CR>
```

Of course, after the first compiling it might be handy to have another mapping just to compile the pdf, since zathura is already open:

```
command Latex !pdflatex %:t
autocmd FileType tex map <leader>tex :w<CR>:Latex<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe `%:r` is what you are looking for, without the `@` character. It will return the file name, without extension.
Also, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605843/get-the-file-name-without-file-extension-in-vim-function).

***EDIT***: I just tested here (not with `!zathura`, but with `!echo`) and the following line should work for you (just append the correct extension after the file name expand):
`command Za !zathura %:r.pdf`

Comment: The problem was actually how to append to filename...

Comment: I just edited the answer. I hope it is clearer now and solves your problem.