# Copy only filename without extension to system clipboard

Tags: vim

Is there a way to only copy/yank the file name to clipboard? According to these sources:
[Yank file name / path of current buffer in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916875/yank-file-name-path-of-current-buffer-in-vim)
[How can I expand the full path of the current file to pass to a command in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233905/how-can-i-expand-the-full-path-of-the-current-file-to-pass-to-a-command-in-vim)
[Get name of the current file in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741024/get-name-of-the-current-file-in-vim)
it is clear that `expand()` is the function to use and the following could be defined:

```
" Full path
nnoremap <leader><leader>f :let @* = expand("%:p")<CR>
" File name, with extension.
nnoremap <leader><leader>n :let @* = expand("%:t")<CR>
" Extension.
nnoremap <leader><leader>e :let @* = expand("%:t:e")<CR>
" Parent directory, full.
nnoremap <leader><leader>p :let @* = expand("%:p:h")<CR>
```

However, I did not find a way to copy the file name only. I mean *file name
without extension*. Is this possible at all? I tried `"%"` and `"%:`. Neither worked.

Comment: What do you want to do on Unix if the file doesn't have an extension?  What if the filename *is* the extension (e.g. the file is named `.txt`)?

Comment: @Kevin: Well, since Vim is case sensitive, I will reserve `<leader><leader>N` for copying the file name with extension, using `"%:t"`. This option will copy the file name that has not extension on it. (Like `_vimrc` on my Window machine)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
expand("%:t:r")
```

does what you want but Kevin raised very good points.

See `:help filename-modifiers`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. For @Kevin's point, as I've tested on Windows, `expand("%:t")` will copy the file name of `_vimrc`, which exactly what he has desired. For Linux, I believe so.